# Angular: Better usage of ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular

Assume I have a case where I have a child component that's displayed only if the input data sent is not undefined. I can code in below ways:

```
<child-component *ngIf="inputData" input-value= "inputData"></child-component>
```

or

```
<child-component input-value= "inputData"></child-component>

// then in child component template:

<div *ngIf="ctrl.inputValue">
    //Child component contents
</div>
```

Which is a better approach & what are the trade offs?

Comment: Depends on ur requirements.. if u want few things of child component to be shown go with second 1 else first 1 is a good way to go with..

Comment: <child-component *ngIf="inputData" input-value= "inputData"></child-component>  this is the best approach

Comment: Using a div is definitely a bad idea if you don't need the div. You can use `ng-container` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<child-component *ngIf="inputData" input-value= "inputData"></child-component>
```

In above line, ngIf will not render child component if it has no data.

```
//Parent Component
<child-component input-value= "inputData"></child-component>

//Child Component

<div *ngIf="ctrl.inputValue">
    //Child component contents
</div>
```

In above code, it follow 3 step process,

- pass value to child component
- invoke child component component to render
- evaluated condition and and render div tags

First one is more optimized solution compare to second one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be on the parent component when you pass the data to the child,

```
<child-component *ngIf="inputData" input-value= "inputData"></child-component>
```

Using this way you can provide true in the parent where the add child-component should be shown and false in the parent where your else path should be taken!

Answer (score 0):

your first code itself will work.

```
<child-component *ngIf="inputData" input-value= "inputData"></child-component>
```

Your child component will be visible if it gets the value alone.